# Not able to resolve local variable while running test using protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, protractor

I am new to protractor and trying to learn the concepts of asynchronous call in protractor.
I am not able to resolve the status of boolean variable which I have set to true in case of any test case fails and execution goes to catch for promise 
Below is the seudo-code snippet.
E.g:

```
var test = function (){
var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
  var abort = false;
for (j = 0; j < testCount; j++) {
  switch (element.toString()) {

    case 'input': 
      handler.execute().then(function(result){
      deferred.fulfill(result);           
       ..
      }).catch(function(err){
        abort = true;
         if(abort){ // goes into if loop
          console.log('abort status'+ abort); // prints as true
         }
         deferred.reject(err);   
      })
     .....
  }

       if(abort){ //control do not go into if loop outside switch caseeven though abort is true
          console.log('abort status'+ abort); 
        break;
         }
}
return deferred.promise;
}
```

This may be silly question but I am not able to get resolve this. 
Thanks again hopefully that's clear enough to understand my problem.

**UPDATES**

Updated the code with promise I have used and added break statement in 2nd if statement to exit the for loop if test case fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive function instead of for loop.

```
var abort = false;

it('should....', function() {
    sampleRecursive(0, testCount, abort)
});

function sampleRecursive(j, testCount, abort) {
    switch (element.toString()) {
        case 'input': 
        handler.execute().then(function(result){
            deferred.fulfill(result);           
            ...
        }).catch(function(err){
            abort = true;
            if(abort){ // goes into if loop
                console.log('abort status'+ abort); // prints as true
            }
            deferred.reject(err);   
        })
        ...
    }
    if (j < testCount && abort == false) {
        sampleRecursive(j + 1, testCount, abort)
    }
}
```

You can update the above function to fit well on your test.
But recursive functions are easier to use than for loop if you are expecting a break at the middle.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paul .... I used this recursive logic and it working like a charm :)

Comment: glad to help! please vote up and marked as answer if you agree :)

Answer (score 0):

As the `handler.execute()` method is running in a background thread, your second `if` is running before you are setting the value for `abort`.

You should move the code in that second `if` into the `catch` clause.

### Edit

Add a waiting loop between the `switch` and the `if(abort)` statements, that waits for the background operation to finish.

Comment: Thanks @Usagi .. Thanks a ton for reply. Actually I was trying to break that for loop if I am getting abort as true . So was trying with the code as below for second if :

 if(abort){ 
          console.log('abort status'+ abort); 
break;
         }

But as control is not going into that 2nd if loop , I am not able to exit that for loop.

Comment: Hi Guys , Any help appreciated . Thanks in advance.